# Laravel Livewire key() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given | nested components | loading a component inside a loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I've been working with [Laravel livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/) for a while now, I've a nested components, which is product list for my site and inside that list I've another component for adding product to wishlist. As per documentation stated [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/nesting-components/) , it says

**"Similar to VueJs, if you render a component inside a loop, Livewire has no way of keeping track of which one is which. To remedy this, livewire offers a special "key" syntax:"**

Like this:

```
<div>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        @livewire('user-profile', $user, key($user->id))
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Here is my code snippets from my project.

```
<div>
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <div class="product-box white-bg mb-8" data-dusk="product"> 
             {{-- here im passing product id as param in key(),  'productList' is a static value for a variable of mount(). --}}
                @livewire('desktop.wish-list-add', $product, key($product->id), 'productList')

            <div class="product-content d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-5">
                ............... 

    @endforeach
    {{ $products->links() }}
</div>
```

The issue is when I try to pass $product->id as param for key(), it gives error

```
key() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given
```

But the doc clearly shows that we have to pass id as param. Has anyone faced this issue so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, I found the solution ( however it doesn't make sense to me , but it works :/ ) 
You have to pass other parameters for mount() like this:

```
@livewire('desktop.wish-list-add', 'productList', $product->id, key($product->id))
```

Instead of this:

```
@livewire('desktop.wish-list-add', $product, key($product->id), 'productList')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@livewire('photos.photo-wire', ['photo' => $photo], key($photo->id))
```

instead of

```
@livewire('photos.photo-wire', ['photo' => $photo, key($photo->id)])
```

because that will generate the error:

`key() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given`